# StreamDecoder vs InputStreamReader when reading malformed files

Tags: java, encoding, nio, malformed

I came across some strange behavior with reading files in Java 8 and i'm wondering if someone can make sense of it.

Scenario:

Reading a malformed text file. By malformed i mean that it contains bytes that do not map to any unicode code points.

The code i use to create such a file is as follows:

```
byte[] text = new byte[1];
char k = (char) -60;
text[0] = (byte) k;
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("/tmp/malformed.log"), text);
```

This code produces a file that contains exactly one byte, which is not part of the ASCII table (nor the extended one).

Attempting to `cat` this file produces the following output:

```
�
```

Which is the [UNICODE Replacement Character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm). This makes sense because UTF-8 needs 2 bytes in order to decode non-ascii characters, but we only have one. This is the behavior i expect from my Java code as well.

Pasting some common code:

```
private void read(Reader reader) throws IOException {

    CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.allocate(8910);

    buffer.flip();

    // move existing data to the front of the buffer
    buffer.compact();

    // pull in as much data as we can from the socket
    int charsRead = reader.read(buffer);

    // flip so the data can be consumed
    buffer.flip();

    ByteBuffer encode = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(buffer);
    byte[] body = new byte[encode.remaining()];
    encode.get(body);

    System.out.println(new String(body));
}
```

Here is my first approach using `nio`:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/malformed.log"));
read(Channels.newReader(inputStream.getChannel(), "UTF-8");
```

This produces the following exception:

```
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1

    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:100)
```

Which is not what i expected but also kind of makes sense, because this is actually a corrupt and an illegal file, and the exception is basically telling us it expected more bytes to be read.

And my second one (using regular `java.io`):

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/malformed.log"));
read(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
```

This does not fail and produces the exact same output as `cat` did:

```
�
```

Which also makes sense.

So my questions are:

1. What is the expected behavior from a Java Application in this scenario?
2. Why is there a difference between using the `Channels.newReader` (which returns a `StreamDecoder`) and simply using the regular `InputStreamReader`? Am i doing something wrong with how i read?

Any clarifications would be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you notice that you're not specifying `UTF-8` for `InputStreamReader`? Is your platform default encoding `UTF-8` or something else? `InputStreamReader` also uses `StreamDecoder` internally.

Comment: "the extended one": which extended one? IBM437 uses all 256 byte values in any sequence. How do you suppose that a text file would be malformed, anyway? Is there something about your application that you must partially process bad input? Can't the bad input can be fixed at the source if the application rejects it? In other words, MalformedInputException is the expected behavior in many cases.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks i didn't notice that. but yes my platform default is UTF-8. i changed the code to specify the Charset and the behavior stays the same. (Edited the code here)

Comment: @TomBlodget i pasted the code i use to create a malformed text file. i dont know how it gets originated on the source because i dont control it. I just wanted to re-create a scenario of malformed text. If a MalformedInputException is the expected behavior, then why dont i see it when using InputStreamReader? what would you say the expected behavior is in this specific case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between the behaviour actually goes right down to the [StreamDecoder and Charset classes](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.java/). The `InputStreamReader` gets a `CharsetDecoder` from `StreamDecoder.forInputStreamReader(..)` which does replacement on error

```
StreamDecoder(InputStream in, Object lock, Charset cs) {
    this(in, lock,
    cs.newDecoder()
    .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
    .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE));
}
```

while the `Channels.newReader(..)` creates the decoder with the default settings (i.e. report instead of replace, which results in an exception further up)

```
public static Reader newReader(ReadableByteChannel ch,
                               String csName) {
    checkNotNull(csName, "csName");
    return newReader(ch, Charset.forName(csName).newDecoder(), -1);
}
```

So they work differently, but there's no indication in documentation anywhere about the difference. This is badly documented, but I *suppose* they changed the functionality because you'd rather get an exception than have your data silently corrupted.

Be careful when dealing with character encodings!